# Apple Mac OS X Lion: the cost and release date

Tags: macos

At which date will MAC OS X Lion be released?

And if I have Mac OS X Snow Leopard, can I upgrade to Lion for free?

Comment: Not really the kind of question that will receive proper attention in this community as far as I can tell.  But, I would hypothesize WWDC, and not free, but probably cheap.

Comment: @harv you really think it's going to be cheap? I see more something like Leopard release price.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff I also think this one will be more expensive than SL. But we can hope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to know that right now. Apple does not disclose such information.

Wait for Apple's June event where they **might** specify the launch date.

One thing is for sure, you'll have to pay for it, there won't be a free migration path from Snow Leopard, unless you bought a Mac computer the week before Lion's release.

Answer (score 0):

Release date and pricing have not been released.

Since Snow Leopard was only $30, it's virtually guaranteed it will not be free.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'release date' is this (northern hemisphere) summer. I *very much* doubt you'll be able to upgrade to Lion for free. Snow Leopard cost US$29. Officially this was for upgrades only, at least initially, but the DVD could be used to do fresh installs too.

With Lion appearing to be more about adding features to the OS, rather than a code clean-up, I suspect this version will cost US$129. This is pure speculation at this stage mind you.